Can I playback audio without needing to ask for microphone permissions in browser?
I am working on a sample app available here
https://github.com/jrgleason/spring-ai-example
The problem I am running into is when the page loads it asks for microphone permissions (see https://thejackiegleason.com for a similar situation). This seems a little bit intrusive so I would like to get audio permissions without the microphone for now. Is there a way to toggle that?
I am sure it is in my face but I can't figure out how to just get playback permissions.
Update
I was asked for more detail so the audio is read here
const mediaSource = new MediaSource();
audio.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
    mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', async () => {

As you can see from a code perspective it is using a typical MediaSource

Questions should include the relevant code, please do not link to github and or your own site.

My bad wrong link didn't have the audio code branch fixed

There is no reason to ask for the microphone if you just want to play sound. What you need is an user-gesture. Your links are still broken, and what you provided in the question shouldn't make this prompt to appear.
